# Did Leia have any hint she was a Force user?

Tags: star-wars, princess-leia

Leia was feisty in her youth. Before ROTJ, did she never get into a situation where her Force powers might show by accident?

Comment: @Machavity the canon's changed a lot since that question, I think the answer will be a lot different this time around

Comment: depends on what you mean by Force powers and her awareness as to whether such an ability was simply 'odd' or if she even recognized it as a 'power' - even in RoTJ she says of her connection to Luke: "I know...I've always known, somehow..." that could be indicative of a Force connection. Anyway, the new canon works have instances of her displaying nascent Force ability (premonitions, visions, etc...)

Comment: @Allball103 The question is fairly vague. As asked, the other question answers this pretty well. But I suspect the OP wants something different. I think he needs to clarify, or someone may close it as a duplicate

Comment: "He is our last hope" "no, there is another" also multiple times we see Leia sensing her brother in the Force "I hope Luke wasn't on that thing when it blew" "He wasn't" etc etc I always took it as given she had force powers

Comment: This is 100% a duplicate. If the answers there aren't sufficient, you should provide a bounty on that question @Machavity was 100% right.

Answer (score 2):

## For Sure!

You have a few scenes to pick from:

1. In ANH she is resistant to "medical" droid .
2. In ESB she receives Luke's call out as they are leaving Cloud City.
3. IN ROTJ she tells Luke that somehow she has always known they were related.

Comment: Also she told han that she KNOWS luke has survived (rotj) as 4th point

Comment: What are you referring to with #1?

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens --- Google "IT-O interrogator". You will remember it when you see it.

Answer (score 1):

I have long presumed that it was no coincidence that, "Her resistance to the mind probe is considerable." Her latent force abilities were probably crucial to her power to withstand Vader's interrogation.